# WTForms decimal separator (for non-English apps)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, wtforms

For non-English apps it's very common to use a ,  as decimal separator.
I can't find any reference to changing the decimal formatting based on the locale.

Is this possible with WTForms?

Answer (score 1):

The [current wtforms code](https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/src/acf20942487e18a1b7cbc542e9130bf0adc111b7/wtforms/fields/core.py?at=default#cl-529) uses the Python [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module, but it totally ignores locale settings about separators (in fact, the documentation presents [an example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#recipes) which builds the string representation building the string representation itself).

You can change the line 561 of `fields\core.py` which is

`format = '%%0.%df' % self.places`

to:

`format = '%%0,%df' % self.places`

but it would be an ugly patch, I suggest to open an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/issues?status=new&status=open) to fix it properly